# How to write equation using latex

Tags: latex, equation, overleaf

I am working on article writing and that's the first time that I use Latex.
How to write complex equations contain cosine with latex.

Comment: maybe https://www.learnlatex.org/ could be a useful resource

Comment: This website is not a do-it-for-me service. You got an answer for one equation, this should be good enough that you can attempt to write the other equations yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
\begin{equation}
    b = \frac{1}{m}(A^T\bm{1}-W^TZ\bm{1}),
\end{equation}
```

to type equation (20). Other equations can be typed similarly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).